# My player - View roster?

Tags: pc, nba2k14

I feel a bit stupid for asking this, but how do I view the rosters of other teams in NBA 2k14 My player mode? I can take a look at the roster of my team but I can't cycle through any other team. I thought I went through everything but didn't have any luck. Surely I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ability to view the rosters of other teams in the Career mode.

Well, aside from the time when your coach comes to you and asks whom you would like him to try and sign.